# Angularjs - refresh controller scope on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Was wondering what is the best way to refresh controller scope on route change?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean when the URL changes but the page and controller stays the same?

Comment: Yep. lets say when I'm navigating from /old_path to /new_path, I want to reset data on OldPathController.

Comment: Are you using built in router or ui router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refactor to have all my initialisation of data properties on the scope in a single function, called something like `initScope()` that is called when the controller is first run, and also on the `$routeChangeSuccess` (and probably also `$routeChangeUpdate` if you want to handle changes to the URL that resolve to the same route) event(s).

e.g.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    function initScope() {
        $scope.foo = 1;
        $scope.bar = { ram: 'ewe' };
    }

    initScope();

    $scope.$on('$routeChangeUpdate', initScope);
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', initScope);
}
```